# Find speed of vehicle from images

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, performance, opticalflow

I am doing a project to find the speed of a vehicle from images. We are taking these images from within the vehicle. We will be marking some object from the 1st image as a reference. Using the properties of the same object in the next image, we must calculate the speed of the moving vehicle. Can anyone help me here??? I am using python opencv. I have succeeded till finding the marked pixel in the 2nd image using Optical flow method. Can anyone help me with the rest?

Comment: Wouldn't this also highly depend on the camera used for taking images? Shutter speed should also be considered.

Comment: there's a lot to consider: e.g. the perpendicular distance of the marking object from your car's line of movement, the time between the 2 images

Comment: you should probably provide some code to show your process. Without that, it will be difficult for anyone to answer.

Comment: Example pictures are always helpful, when asking an `image-processing` question.

Comment: I am currently considering all the possibilities. The code till now is basically a partially edited lkdemo.py found in Opencv samples.

Comment: Its easier to find the camera properties using the metadata of the image which will be attached to the image by the camera itself. So thats not a problem. What I want is the procedure after this.

Comment: I have uploaded the present code at http://code.google.com/p/vehiclespeedopencv/downloads/list

Comment: Do you have a compass in the car for bearing information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Knowing the acquisition frequency, you must now find the distance between the successive positions of the marker.

To find this distance, I suggest you estimate the *pose* of the marker for each image. Loosely speaking, the "pose" is the transformation matrix expressing the coordinates of an object relative to a camera. Once you have those successive coordinates, you can compute the distance, and then the speed.

Pose estimation is the process of computing the position and orientation of a **known** 3D object relative to a 2D camera. The resulting pose is the transformation matrix describing the object's referential in the camera's referential.

[image: Pose description]

OpenCV implements a pose estimation algorithm: **[Posit](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit)**. The doc says:

> Given some 3D points (in object
>   coordinate system) of the object, at
>   least four non-coplanar points, their
>   corresponding 2D projections in the
>   image, and the focal length of the
>   camera, the algorithm is able to
>   estimate the object's pose.

This means:

1. You must know the focal length of your camera
2. You must know the geometry of your marker
3. You must be able to match four know points of your marker in the 2D image

You may have to compute the focal length of the camera using the [calibration routines](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) provided by OpenCV. I think you have the two other required data.

**Edit:**

```
// Algorithm example

MarkerCoords = {Four coordinates of know 3D points}

I1 = take 1st image
F1 = focal(I1)
MarkerPixels1 = {Matching pixels in I1}
Pose1 = posit(MarkerCoords, MarkerPixels1, F1)

I2 = take 2nd image
F2 = focal(I2)
MarkerPixels2 = {Matching pixels in I2 by optical flow}
Pose2 = posit(MarkerCoords, MarkerPixels2, F2)

o1 = origin_of_camera * Pose1 // Origin of camera is
o2 = origin_of_camera * Pose2 // typically [0,0,0]
dist = euclidean_distance(o1, o2)
speed = dist/frequency
```

**Edit 2:** (Answers to comments)

> "What is the acquisition frequency?"

Computing the speed of your vehicle is equivalent to computing the speed of the marker. (In the first case, the referential is the marker attached to the earth, in the second case, the referential is the camera attached to the vehicle.) This is expressed by the following equation:

```
speed = D/(t2-t1)
```

With:

- `D` the distance `[o1 o2]`
- `o1` the position of the marker at time `t1`
- `o2` the position of the marker at time `t2`

You can retrieve the elapsed time either by extracting `t1` and `t2` from the metadata of your photos, or from the *acquisition frequency* of your imaging device: `t2-t1 = T = 1/F`.

> "Won't it be better to mark simple things like posters? And if doing so can't we consider it as a 2d object?"

This is not possible with the Posit algorithm (or with any other pose estimation algorithm as far as I know): it requires four **non-coplanar** points. This means you cannot chose a 2D object embedded in a 3D space, you have to chose an object with some depth.

On the other hand, you can use a *really* simple shape, as far as it is a volume. (A cube for example.)

Comment: I have a serious doubt. Since we will have the liberty to mark objects on our own, wont it be better to mark simple things like posters(mainly rectangle in shape)? And if doing so cant we consider it as a 2d object? And what is acquisition frequency? I'm a bit new to such kind of terms.