# Detect speed of few cars from video- Python

Tags: python, numpy, camera, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a program that use speed camera (with Raspberry Pi Camera Board)
And should take photos of cars which speed is higher than given one, and send this photos to a policeman that waiting down the road, and save the number of the car.

I have a video that records from this angle:
[Angle of capturing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjfwf.jpg)
I have a few problems:

1. There are many cars that driving at the same time, and I need to get info about all of them
2. I can't calculate the speed- maybe the problem occurs because I don't know how to deal with a few cars together

I have tried the algorithm that described here, but maybe I don't understand it well:

[Find the speed of the vehicle from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872570/find-speed-of-vehicle-from-images)

That's the part of my code where I try to detect the speed:
* In the code I detect a point at the centre of the car and following it while the car moving, I understand that I need to get X, Y points and X1, Y1 points, the time between them, and make a calculation. 
But when i use it: `print('centre',centroid[0:2])` i get only one point (x).

```
def update_vehicle(self, vehicle, matches):
    # Find if any of the matches fits this vehicle
    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        contour, centroid = match

        vector = self.get_vector(vehicle.last_position, centroid)
        if self.is_valid_vector(vector):
            vehicle.add_position(centroid)
            self.log.debug("Added match (%d, %d) to vehicle #%d. vector=(%0.2f,%0.2f)"
                , centroid[0], centroid[1], vehicle.id, vector[0], vector[1])

            #i detect the centre of the car and follow it, I've thought, how can I use the info of points of the centre and
            #use it to detect the car, the problem is: I can't understand how to take this info,
            #i need the X & Y point,
            print(centre',centroid[0:2])

            return i

    # No matches fit...
    vehicle.frames_since_seen += 1

    self.log.debug("No match for vehicle #%d. frames_since_seen=%d"
        , vehicle.id, vehicle.frames_since_seen)

    return None
```

and this is the function of *centroid* that i use there:

```
def get_centroid(x, y, w, h):
    x1 = int(w / 2)

    y1 = int(h / 2)

    cx = x + x1
    cy = y + y1

    return (cx, cy)
```